# Excel VBA: Filter and copy from top 5 rows/cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table which is sorted on descending order in column F.  I then need to copy the top 5 rows, but only data from Column A, B, D, and F (not the headers).  See pictures.

```
Sub top5()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$T$321").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Dave"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("F4:F321"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

' This copy-paste part does what its supposed to, but only for the specific 
' cells.  Its not generalised and I will have to repeat this operation
' several times for different people
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A3:B15").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("D3:D15").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("F3:F15").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("D3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I thought about trying to adapt this snippet of code below using visible cells function, but I'm stuck and I can't find anything on the net which fits.

```
' This selects all rows (plus 1, probably due to offset), I only want parts of from the top 5.
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$B$321").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$4:$D$321").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I hope my example makes sense and I really appreciate your help!

[image: Sample Excel table]

Note:  The heading names are only the same in the two tables to show that the data is the same.  The headers are NOT supposed to be copied.  In addition, there is an extra column/white space in the second table.  A solution should include this.

[image: Data copied to new table]

Comment: A `Do...Loop` block would work wonders with your snippet.  Just loop through the rows one by one and when you've copied 5 rows, exit the loop.

Comment: How does that look @jbarker2160?  How do I loop through the visible rows?  I know what you mean but I'm struggling to know how to execute it...

Comment: a) Your sample code shows the copied results pasted into row 3 of the target worksheet but your sample images show row 5. What is the actual target row? b) Is it necessary to preserve the 'whitespace' on the target worksheet's columns C and E? Is there a possibility that there may be values there that would be overwritten with a block paste?

Comment: Hi @Jeeped.  This is actually for a report at work so I can't obviously give any of the actual data or the report.  This table, and two others like it, are in the middle of a page of tables and graphs and I cannot change the whitespace etc so a block select, paste, delete type approach wouldn't work.  Also, I only show the operation for the column F but I would repeat it on column H, and then again on J.  All the copied data will be in same columns (ie. A, B, D, and F) in the new page but not in the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly a few helpful points:

- You should refer to worksheets by there [Code Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) to avoid renaming issues.
- If you want to work with VBA then my advice is to avoid merged cells like the plague.  They cause havoc with code.  If possible use format cells - alignment - horizontal - centre accross selection
- I also advise [avoiding loops](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm) wherever possible and take advantage of excels built in functions instead as a good practice exercise.

Here is my solution.  Keep it simple.  If you need further help let me now.

```
Sub HTH()

    Dim rCopy As Range

    With Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range
        '// Set to somewhere blank and unused on your worksheet
        Set rCopy = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count - (.Rows.Count))
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy rCopy
    End With

    With rCopy.Offset(1).Resize(5) '// Offset to avoid the header
        .Resize(, 2).Copy Sheet2.Range("A5")
        .Offset(, 3).Resize(, 1).Copy Sheet2.Range("D5")
        .Offset(, 5).Resize(, 1).Copy Sheet2.Range("F5")
        .CurrentRegion.Delete xlUp '// Delete the tempory area
    End With

    Set rCopy = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: 1.  That's interesting, I didn't know that!  Will definitely look at using that in the future.  2.  Sorry mate, merged cells is not my choice.  For the moment that is something I can't change.  3.  Yup.  I agree.  But you also have to work with what you know and right now I don't know a lot ;-)

Comment: With a little bit of twiddling, I was able to understand which bit of the code did what and bend it to my will.  Thanks very much.  It was quite simple and I liked the lack of loops.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.  Yes sometimes merged cells are unavoidable, just make them a last resort.  So also are loops but avoiding them where possible usually will result in faster execution of code as your taking advantage of excels builtin features.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to use `Union` and `Intersect` to only copy the cells that you want.  If you are pasting values (or the data is not a formula to start), this works well.  Thinking about it, it builds a range of columns to keep using `Union` and then `Intersect` that with the first 5 rows of data with 2 header rows.  The result is a copy of only the data you want with formatting intact.

**Edit only process visible rows, grabbing the header, and then the first 5 below the header rows**

```
Sub CopyTopFiveFromSpecificColumns()

    'set up the headers first to keep
    Dim rng_top5 As Range
    Set rng_top5 = Range("3:4").EntireRow

    Dim int_index As Integer
    'start below the headers and keep all the visible cells
    For Each cell In Intersect( _
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(5), _
        Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

        'add row to keepers
        Set rng_top5 = Union(rng_top5, cell.EntireRow)

        'track how many items have been stored
        int_index = int_index + 1
        If int_index >= 5 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    'copy only certain columns of the keepers
    Intersect(rng_top5, _
        Union(Range("A:A"), _
                Range("B:B"), _
                Range("D:D"), _
                Range("F:F"))).Copy

    'using Sheet2 here, you can set to wherever, works if data is not formulas
    Range("Sheet2!A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'if the data contains formulas, use this route
    'Range("Sheet2!A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Range("Sheet2!A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

Here is the result I get from some dummy data set up in the same ranges as the picture above.

**Sheet1 with copied range visible**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet2 with pasted data**

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: This looks good, but its not copying the filtered data... its giving me the top 5 lines, but not the top 5 lines after I've filtered for Dave... :-s

Comment: Good point.  I thought they were sorted for some reason in the picture above.  I edited the code so that it only grabs visible rows.

Comment: Oooh so close!  Just two things - the headers are proving to be a trouble, particularly because some of them are merged cells.  I'm thinking I should just do away with them, but taking out the 4th line of code "set rng_5" creates problems later in the subroutine.  How do I fix that?  Some sort of "If rng_5 empty, set to first line"?  Secondly, there is some column padding in the copied-to sheet - how do I incorporate that in to the intersect?  FYI, one of the columns I'm copying from, column D, has formulas.

Comment: Yo!  @Byron Wall.  Any chance you can help me out here? I've been thinking about this a lot and doing a lot of googling searching but I'm just not finding the right info to help me with this.  Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question, selecting the top5 visible cells, is relatively easy, the copying and pasting is where the trouble are. You see, you cannot paste a range, even if it is not uniform, into non uniform range. So you'll need to write your own Paste function.

**Part 1 - Getting the Top5 rows**

I used a similar technique to @Byron's. Notice that this is merely a function returning a `Range` object and accepting a `String`, which represents your non-uniform range (you can change the parameter type to `Range` if you wish).

```
Function GetTop5Range(SourceAddress As String) As Range
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngVisible As Range
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Dim rngTop5 As Range

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngSource = Range(SourceAddress)
    Set rngVisible = rngSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(rngVisible, rngVisible.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn)

    i = 1
    For Each cell In rngIntersect
        If i = 1 Then
            Set rngTop5 = cell.EntireRow
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf i > 1 And i < 6 Then
            Set rngTop5 = Union(rngTop5, cell.EntireRow)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    Set GetTop5Range = Intersect(rngTop5, rngVisible)
End Function
```

**Part 2 - Creating your own pasting function**

Because Excel always pastes your copied range as uniform, you need to do it yourself. This method essentially breaks down your source region to columns and pastes them individually. The method accepts parameter SourceRange of type `Range` , which is meant to by your Top5 range, and a TopLeftCornerRange of type `Range`, which represents the target cell of your pasting.

```
Sub PasteRange(SourceRange As Range, TopLeftCornerRange As Range)
    Dim rngColumnRange As Range

    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngColumnRange = Intersect(SourceRange, SourceRange.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow)

    For Each cell In rngColumnRange
        Intersect(SourceRange, cell.EntireColumn).Copy
        TopLeftCornerRange.Offset(0, cell.Column - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Next cell

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Part 3 - Running the procedure**

```
Sub Main()
    PasteRange GetTop5Range("A2:B33,D2:D33"), Range("A35")
End Sub
```

That's it.

In my project, I had source data in Columns A, B and D like you did and the results are pasted to range beginning at A35.

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub GetTopFiveRows()
    Dim table As Range, cl As Range, cnt As Integer

    Set table = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    cnt = 1

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cl In table
            If cnt <= 5 Then
                .Range("A" & cnt) = cl
                .Range("B" & cnt) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
                .Range("D" & cnt) = cl.Offset(0, 3)
                .Range("F" & cnt) = cl.Offset(0, 5)
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

- First a reference is set to only visible rows in the entire table (you'll need to update the range reference)
- Then we loop over the visible range, copy to sheet 2, and stop when 5 records (i.e. the top five) have been copied

Answer (score 0):

While it may simply be easier to loop through the first five visible rows, I used application.evaluate to process a worksheet-style formula that returned the row number of the fifth visible record.

```
Sub sort_filter_copy()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, flr As Long, rws As Long, v As Long
    Dim sCRIT As String
    Dim vCOLs As Variant, vVALs As Variant
    Dim bCopyFormulas As Boolean, bSort2Keys As Boolean

    bCopyFormulas = True
    bSort2Keys = False
    sCRIT = "dave"
    vCOLs = Array(1, 2, 4, 6)

    With Sheet1
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Cells(5, 1).Resize(lr - 4, lc)
            'sort on column F as if there was no header
            If bSort2Keys Then
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(6), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Key2:=.Columns(7), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            Else
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(6), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            End If
            With .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, .Columns.Count)
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=sCRIT
                With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                    rws = Application.Min(5, Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3)))
                    If CBool(rws) Then
                        flr = Application.Evaluate("=small(index(rows(5:" & lr & ") + ('" & Sheet1.Name & "'!C5:C" & lr & "<>" & Chr(34) & sCRIT & Chr(34) & ")*1e99, , ), " & rws & ")")
                        For v = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
                            If .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Cells(1).HasFormula And bCopyFormulas Then
                                Sheet2.Cells(3, vCOLs(v)).Resize(5, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                                    .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Cells(1).FormulaR1C1
                            Else
                                .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Resize(flr - 4, 1).Copy _
                                    Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(3, vCOLs(v))
                            End If
                        Next v
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter
            End With
            'uncomment the next line if you want to return to a standard ascending sort on column A
            '.Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

All options are set just below the variable declarations. Your sample images seemed to indicate that you used a two key sort so I coded for that optionally. If you want to bring in any formulas as formulas, that option is there. The filter criteria and the columns to copy are assigned to their respective vars as well.

[image: Sort, Filter and Copy Top 5]

My sample workbook is available on my public DropBox at:
      [Sort_Filter_Copy_from_Top_5.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Sort_Filter_Copy_from_Top_5.xlsb)

Answer (score 0):

First Unmerge the cells then use this code, very similar to some of the other suggestions.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, fRng As Range, c As Range, fRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(Rws, "T"))    'unmerge all the headers


    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Dave"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
            Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Range("F4:F321"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Set fRng = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Rws, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    x = 0

    For Each c In fRng.Cells

        If x = 5 Then Exit Sub
        fRw = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        sh.Range(sh.Cells(fRw, 1), sh.Cells(fRw, 2)).Value = Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 2)).Value
        sh.Cells(fRw, 4).Value = Cells(c.Row, 4).Value
        sh.Cells(fRw, 6).Value = Cells(c.Row, 6).Value
        x = x + 1

    Next c
End Sub
```