# Using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) - Skip Hidden cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to get only the cells that are visible. My objective is to pull upto 5 records after the Filter Criteria is applied.

However, after the filter is applied and there are hidden cells, only the sequential ones are fetched and anything after the hidden rows are not
getting pulled.

Is there a way to skip the Hidden cells and get upto 5 entries.

---

```
    Dim rRange As Range, filRange As Range
        Dim value1 As String
        Dim value2 As String
        Dim strItemNameBF() As String
        Dim iCol As Long
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim loopCnt As Integer
        Dim chk As String
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
    Dim rAcells As Range

        'Sheets("Test Log").Select
        Sheets("Test Log").AutoFilterMode = False

        Set rRange = Sheets("Test Log").Range("TestLog")


        With rRange
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=projectID
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Red", "Yellow", "Green"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
                Set filRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


      If filRange.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                If filRange.Rows.Count > 5 Then
                  loopCnt = 5
                Else
                  loopCnt = filRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: (1) Please indicate which region `TestLog` covers. (2) End with and End Ifs are missing from the code

Comment: (3) do a simpler Autofilter function. I believe the issue is because the Autofilter might not be filtering correctly. To check this, comment out the `.AutoFilter` line in the code, and check the value for `filRange.Rows.Count`. This should be equal to the number of visible cells in filter that you do manually

Comment: This is oddly similar to the bounty question at [Excel VBA: Filter and copy from top 5 rows/cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633244/excel-vba-filter-and-copy-from-top-5-rows-cells).

Comment: Don't rely on `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. There is a known bug where this will return the rows from row 2 down to the bottom of the worksheet if there are no visible cells. Use `application.subtotal(103, ...` to get a count before selecting the visible rows with specialcells.